# Who put the Hangman game on the refrigerator?

Tags: the-machinist

In *The Machinist* (2004), Trevor Reznik sees a piece of paper on the refrigerator with a game of Hangman, and he later tries to solve it. Who put it there?

Comment: It could have been himself as he is in such a bad shape that he has a memory problem OR this piece of paper never does exist, all is happening in his head

Comment: One of the production assistants